# How to capture consecutive characters in a string

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex

I have a string `'aabaaa'`. How could I use a regex to capture consecutive characters so that I get something like the following?

```
[['aa'], ['b'], ['aaa']]
```

I am interested in determining how many times each character occurs consecutively.

Comment: A web based tool I try regex in is http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: [`(\w)\1{0,}`](https://regex101.com/r/M4yy4O/1)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yep, edited the post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just out of curiosity:

**ruby >= 2.4**

```
'aabaaa'.each_char.chunk_while(&:==).map(&:join) # or .map(&:length)
#⇒ ["aa", "b", "aaa"]
```

**ruby >= 2.3** (credits to Cary Swoveland)

```
'aabaaa'.each_char.chunk(&:itself).map(&:join)
```

**∀ ruby**

```
'aabaaa'.scan(/(\w)(\1*)/).map(&:join)
#⇒ ["aa", "b", "aaa"]

'aabaaa'.scan(/(\w)(\1*)/).map(&:join).map(&:length)
#⇒ [2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. I wasn't aware of chunk_while but it's very neat!

Comment: No solution for Ruby v2.4?? For >= 2.3, consider `'aabaaa'.each_char.chunk(&:itself).map(&:join)` (itself` came with 2.3).

Comment: For #2, also `'aabaaa'.gsub(/(\w)\1*/).with_object([]) { |s,a| a << s }`. I seem to find lots of uses for `gsub` without a block, which returns an enumerator, resulting in no character replacements.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `gsub` without a block, which returns an enumerator, is likely implemented in ruby core library and called... `scan` :)

Comment: ...except the two treat capture groups differently. `'aabaaa'.scan(/(\w)(\1*)/) { |s| puts s }` prints `a`, `a`, `b` on successive lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/(\w)(?=\1|[^\1])\1+|(\w)(?!\2)/g)` to match word character followed by one or more of capture group or word not followed by capture group.

Or, as suggested by @mudasobwa use `RegExp` `/(\w)(\1*)/g`.

To get `.length` of each matched group you can create an array, iterate array of matches, push object having property set to either first element of match or the matched group itself. Or utilize `Array.prototype.map()` to return `.length` of each matched group.

```
"aabaaa".match(/(\w)(?=\1)\1+|(\w)(?!\2)/g)
```

```js
let str = "aabaaa";

let groups = str.match(/(\w)(?=\1)\1+|(\w)(?!\2)/g);

let matches = [];

for (let match of groups) {
  matches.push({[match]: match.length});
}

let len = groups.map(({length}) => length);

console.log(groups, matches, len);
```

Comment: `str.match(/(\w)(\1*)/g)`

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby,

```
'aabaaa'.scan(/(?<s>(?<c>.)\k<c>*)/).map(&:first)
# => ["aa", "b", "aaa"]

'aabaaa'.scan(/(?<s>(?<c>.)\k<c>*)/).map{|s, _| s.length}
# => [2, 1, 3]
```